# Use Static / Known SSH keys on GCE

Tags: linux, ssh, security, google-compute-engine

We are often dropping and re-creating machines on Google Compute Engine to tear up and down testing environments, perform failover tests, etc.

The problem is that GCE is always re-creating the SSH server keys on each new instance that is created from an image or a snapshot.

What is an easy way to have static SSH keys or SSH keys that are readily accept across machines when doing scp or ssh operations?

Comment: The solution I have in mind kind of reduce security:
- use a static key that is copied by a startup script and shared across machines

Answer (score 1):

If you are using your machines only for testing (testing something elste then `ssh` itself of course) and the security is no issue (closed environment), you can make it part of your install script/kickstart/first boot to pull the keys from somewhere and not generate its own (the way what triggers key generation differ between distributions, but you will find out - RHEL creates them only if they are missing during first service start).

Comment: Thanks. We're using ubuntu, it behaves the same AFAIK. Any tips on standards for this? Ideally i'm looking for a way to pull the key from a server that generates them in a secure manner, different per system and we can distribute them to all our users on the machines.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a private key `google_compute_engine` file in your `/home/<username>/.ssh/` directory, then using `gcloud compute ssh <target instance>` command should not generate a new key. However, if you'll be using a different username or trying to SSH from a newly created VM instance, the `gcloud compute ssh` command will generate a new private/public key to comply the security requirements.

You can copy the private key to a specific machine or your local computer and always SSH from there. This will eliminate generating new keys.

If this is about SSH Host Key, then you can use `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` option with your ssh command (OpenSSH) to bypass the checking of the host key's authenticity.

Comment: Sorry, I was talking about the SSHD (server) keys, not user keys.

Comment: If this is about SSH Host Key, then you can use `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` option with your ssh command (OpenSSH) to bypass the checking of the host key authenticity.

Comment: Thanks, that was also an idea, here I was considering it as a security issue, but probably is not much difference if using static keys that are generated versus just ignoring the checks.